# Cannot Modify / Delete files over samba share

Tags: linux, permissions, samba

I have a directory on my Linux machine that I want to share to my Windows machine. I want to be able to modify / delete these files from the Windows PC. I've installed and am using Samba to share the directory. I am able view the directory from windows, however I am unable to rename a file (modify) or delete a file. When I attempt to do so, I get an error saying: "You require permission from Unix User\root to make changes to this file".

Here is my smb file (it's grown a bit messy):

```
[global]
    unix charset = UTF-8
    dos charset = CP932
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
    server string = Samba Server Version %v
    security = SHARE
    passdb backend = tdbsam
    username map = /etc/samba/smbusers
    hosts allow = 127., 10., 192.168., 172.
    cups options = raw

[printers]
        comment = All Printers
        path = /var/spool/samba
        browseable = no
        guest ok = no
        writable = no
        printable = yes

[VRL]
   path = /opt/vmpro/VRL
   writable = yes
   guest ok = yes
   guest only = yes
   create mode = 0777
   directory mode = 0777
   share modes = yes
   readonly = no
```

smbusers

```
nobody=*
```

stat /opt/vmpro/VRL returns this:

```
  File: `/opt/vmpro/VRL'
  Size: 819200          Blocks: 1608       IO Block: 4096   directory
Device: 803h/2051d      Inode: 4989348     Links: 3
Access: (0777/drwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (  495/   vmpro)   Gid: (  490/   vmpro)
Access: 2017-01-20 17:13:52.000000000 -0500
Modify: 2017-01-20 17:14:00.000000000 -0500
Change: 2017-01-20 17:14:00.000000000 -0500
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: per request, here is the result of an ls of a file. Notice that I changed it's permissions as well, the result still not changing.

```
[root@000C290909A5 VRL]# ls -l /opt/vmpro/VRL/MSG366229159120586_192.168.80.29.wav
-rw-rw-r--. 1 vmpro vmpro 52122 Jan 19 10:13 /opt/vmpro/VRL/MSG366229159120586_192.168.80.29.wav
[root@000C290909A5 VRL]# chmod 0777 MSG366229159120586_192.168.80.29.wav
[root@000C290909A5 VRL]# ls -l /opt/vmpro/VRL/MSG366229159120586_192.168.80.29.wav
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 vmpro vmpro 52122 Jan 19 10:13 /opt/vmpro/VRL/MSG366229159120586_192.168.80.29.wav
```

Comment: How about showing us `ls -l /opt/vmpro/VRL/fileNotUpdatable`?  It would also be good to know if you can create new files in the share's root.

Comment: @JuliePelletier I updated the question with the ls results. Also, I attempted to create a new text file via windows and that failed with, "You need permission to perform this action".

Comment: Does `setsebool -P allow_smbd_anon_write=1` solve it?

Comment: I've disabled selinux entirely, still no dice.

Comment: Can you create new files from Windows?

Comment: OK, and does adding `guest account = vmpro` to your samba config make a difference after you restart it?

Comment: Please get back to us to know what we should do with this question.  If the solution is to specify the guest account as I suspect (my last comment), it could be answered and useful, if not the situation is still too unclear to get a proper answer and should be closed as such.